# How do I get more than 10 message attachments from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

When I query Microsoft Graph API to return attachments of an email then only a maximum of 10 attachments are returned (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_list_attachments).

I'm facing the same issue with Microsoft Outlook v2.0 API.

It seems that the OData query parameters like "filter", "skip" and "top" are not supported from  *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments*.
The query doesn't return any `@odata.nextLink` property.

I'm using javascript and jQuery to get the attachements of a message.

Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: have you fixed this? If you fixed please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't reproduce this with either Graph (using [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer)) or Outlook APIs (using [OAuth Sandbox](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net)). I've got a message with 24 attachments and they all come back. Can you try those portals and see if you only get 10?